# What is the difference between IN and EXISTS

Tags: subquery

I am reading tutorials and practice webs and I don't see the difference between `IN` and `EXISTS`

And one more question:

when should I put the subquery in the `SELECT` section, in the `FROM` section, in the `WHERE` section, in the `HAVING` section?